# Временное хранение token

Tags: android

Я получаю после авторизации token, насколько правильно использовать глобальную переменную в качестве временного хранения (жизненный цикл приложения)?

Comment: по-моему лучший вариант для хранения токена - найтройки sharedPreferences. Можно взять токен в любой части приложения и не беспокоится за жизненный цикл приложения.

Comment: Я не беспокоюсь за жизненный цикл приложения, меня интересует вопрос в правильности применения глобальной переменной для хранения токена.

Comment: я бы вам посоветовал воспользоваться sharedPreferences, на мой взгляд этот вариант получше

Comment: да, хранить токен в глобальной переменной это ок. Особенно если это сессионный токен. То есть меняется каждый раз, когда приложение запускается

Comment: Спасибо, буду использовать в глобальной))